# regex to convert www.evernote.com URL to use evernote protocol

Tags: regex, bash, sed, keyboard-maestro

I'm writing a simple script that will take URLs pointing to Evernote notes online, and convert them to the `evernote:///` protocol. The regex I'm using matches and modifies the URL correctly when I try it out in a regex tester (I'm using Patterns for OS X). However, when I use it with sed, it just returns the original string.

`echo "https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/nl/227468/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/" | sed  's#https?:_/_/www_.evernote_.com_/shard_/(..)_/nl_/(......)_/(.+_/)#evernote:_/_/_/view_/$2_/$1_/$3$3#'`

Any idea why this isn't working? Thanks!

fort

[Edit: In case anyone's interested, this was for the AppleScript bit of a Keyboard Maestro macro:

`set theURL to the clipboard
 set ENcode to "echo \"" & theURL & "\" | sed -E 's#https?://www.evernote.com/shard/(..)/nl/(.*)/(.+/)#evernote:///view/\\2/\\1/\\3\\3#' | pbcopy"
 do shell script ENcode`

Thanks to @DreadPirateShawn for helping me fix the regex.
]

Comment: Are you sure that your regex works correctly in the regex tester with all those underscores?

Comment: @devnull it does, but you need to pass the flag to tell it to use them, just like every other system.

Comment: @devnull it's `-E` on OSX.

Comment: @Kevin Aha! Right, that stupid OSX after all.

Comment: BTW, sed isn't perl.  You denote backreferences by saying `\1` and such, not `$1` and so on.

Comment: @devnull I know, I'm a bit dopey today :( Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the extended regex flag `-E`, removing the underscores, and replacing each `$1` pattern with `\1` yields a functional regex here:

```
$ echo "https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/nl/227468/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/" | sed -E 's#https?://www\.evernote\.com/shard/(..)/nl/(......)/(.+/)#evernote:///view/\2/\1/\3\3#'
evernote:///view/227468/s2/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/
```

(Confirmed on Ubuntu 12.04 and OS X.)

If you don't use `-E`, then you also need to change `s?` to `[s]?` and escape the grouping parentheses:

```
$ echo "https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/nl/227468/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/" | sed  's#http[s]*://www\.evernote\.com/shard/\(.*\)/nl/\(.*\)/\(.*/\)#evernote:///view/\2/\1/\3\3#'
evernote:///view/227468/s2/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/
```

In the latter example, I also replaced each `(....)`-type sequence with `(.*)` -- unless you're absolutely positive of the length of each sequence (and even then perhaps), the `(.*)` approach will be a bit more flexible.

Comment: PS: Not being familiar with the evernote protocol, I'm assuming that the repeated group 3 -- `$3$3` -- is intentional.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. My final version is: ```echo "https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/nl/227468/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/" | /usr/local/bin/sed -E 's#https?:\/\/www\.evernote\.com\/shard\/(..)\/nl\/(......)\/(.+\/)#evernote:\/\/\/view\/\2\/\1\/\3\3#'```

Comment: And yes, the output should look like this: ```evernote:///view/227468/s2/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/```

Comment: Escaping the dots just occurred to me right before your comment :-) so I've updated the answer to include that as well. That said, you *don't* need to escape your front-slashes, specifically because you're using `#` as your regex segment delineator. Saves on visual noise to omit those.

Comment: Actually, I took your advice re. the ```(.*)``` as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying this:

```
echo "https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/nl/227468/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/" | sed -re 's#https://www.evernote.com/shard/(..)/nl/(......)/(.+)/#evernote://view/\2/\1/\3#'
evernote://view/227468/s2/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359
```

Making no use of Extended regex:

```
echo "https://www.evernote.com/shard/s2/nl/227468/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359/" | sed  's#https://www.evernote.com/shard/\(..\)/nl/\(......\)/\(.\+\)/#evernote://view/\2/\1/\3#'
evernote://view/227468/s2/1875e55a-e512-4cf9-9b18-9e93c6a27359
```